# Flutter issue with using the app on the simulator as well as on a physical device

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to test my app however this keeps happening. The only thing I did that could have had this result was to upgrade flutter using `flutter upgrade`. When I run `flutter doctor` everything comes back passing. I've also run `flutter pub get` so my packages should be correct.

I'm not actually sure what the error is otherwise I would be more specific, but here is the error traceback:

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    mkdir -p /Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks
    rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.framework" "/Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks"
    building file list ... done
    FBSDKCoreKit.framework/
    FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit
    FBSDKCoreKit.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
    sent 1572952 bytes  received 70 bytes  3146044.00 bytes/sec
    total size is 1817194  speedup is 1.16
    Code Signing /Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework with Identity -
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign -  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework'
    /Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework: replacing existing signature
    rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.framework" "/Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks"
    building file list ... done
    FBSDKLoginKit.framework/
    FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit
    FBSDKLoginKit.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
    sent 285006 bytes  received 70 bytes  570152.00 bytes/sec
    total size is 285441  speedup is 1.00
Code Signing /Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework with Identity -
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign -  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework'
    /Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework: replacing existing signature
    rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FMDB/FMDB.framework" "/Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks"
    building file list ... done
    FMDB.framework/
    FMDB.framework/FMDB
    FMDB.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
    sent 228080 bytes  received 70 bytes  456300.00 bytes/sec
    total size is 228523  speedup is 1.00
    Code Signing /Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework with Identity -
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign -  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework'
    /Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/FMDB.framework: replacing existing signature
    rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/ios/Pods/../Flutter/Flutter.framework" "/Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks"
    building file list ... done
Flutter.framework/
    Flutter.framework/Flutter
    Flutter.framework/Info.plist
    Flutter.framework/icudtl.dat
    Flutter.framework/_CodeSignature/
    Flutter.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
    sent 94440044 bytes  received 120 bytes  62960109.33 bytes/sec
    total size is 94428117  speedup is 1.00
    Stripped /Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter of architectures: armv7 arm64
    Code Signing /Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework with Identity -
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign -  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework'
    /Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework: replacing existing signature
    /Users/garrettlove/development/projects/crcle/crcle_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework: Permission denied
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am on a Mac using 10.15.1. Something to note which changed in macOS Catalina is that Apple became more strict on what app they allow you open, so now the only options in Security and Privacy settings are "App Store" and "App Store and identified developers". If you follow the steps in this article to allow apps that are downloaded from anywhere this issue seems to go away

https://www.imore.com/how-open-apps-anywhere-macos-catalina-and-mojave